# Use the efficient duque(collection) class in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import pandas as pd
from collections import deque

def extract_information():
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    dates=deque([])
    times=deque([])
    codes=deque([])
    messages=deque([])
    xtree=et.parse("log.xml")
    xroot=xtree.getroot()
    for i in xroot.iter('list'):
        codes.append(i.get('code'))
        messages.append(i.get('message'))
    for j in codes:
        temp=xroot.find('*/log[@code="{0}"]'.format(j))
        times.append(temp.get('time'))
        father=xroot.find('*/log[@code="{0}"]..'.format(j))
        dates.append(father.get('date'))
    result=pd.DataFrame({'Date':dates,'Time':times,'Code':codes,'Message':messages})
    #'Date':dates,
    return result
extract_information()
```

In this code I used the duque class instead of my list to do the simple append work. My confusion is that when constructing a dataframe in the pandas docs, it only mentions using dict to construct it, using the example {'key': [xxx]}, but in the python docs duque is not a subclass of list, so pandas exactly why can check duque class it

Comment: Why are you using a `deque` instead of a list, when all you're doing is appending?  Your code would work just as well with `dates = []`, and the same for the other things.  And to answer your question.  Python is very forgiving when it comes to types.  A `deque` can pretty much do everything a `list` can do, and it pretty much performs the exact same operation.  Python doesn't do type checking, and in this case, is none the wiser.

Comment: And looking at the documentation:  "Dict can contain Series, arrays, constants, dataclass or list-like objects. If data is a dict, column order follows insertion-order."  A deque is a list-like object.